# unable to create an entry with chinese characters in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a platform for chinese students in ruby on rails. This is my schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130827203308) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text    "message"
    t.integer "student_id"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["student_id"], name: "index_posts_on_student_id", using: :btree

  create_table "students", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "number"
    t.string   "college"
    t.string   "password"
    t.float    "budget"
    t.string   "picture"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

when I head to the rails console and do this

```
Post.create(:message => "I am looking at a 3 bedroom apartment")
```

I can Begin and Commit this into my db.

But when I do

```
Post.create(:message => "我在Suffolk University附近想租一个3房一厅的apt有没有同学有兴趣“)
```

my rails console freeze.

I am using the type "text" for my messages in the posts table. Should I be using "string" ? or should I be using some sort of a language gem to do this?

Comment: @bredikhin yes and is the rails c any different than if I am not?

Comment: Yes, it would be different `irb`.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `readline` package with `rvm` and recompile your ruby:

```
$ rvm pkg install readline
$ rvm install <your_ruby_version>
```